# Removing MediaPlayer's Log call using proguard

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, proguard, android-videoview

I'm trying to remove all logs from my final signed apk with proguard. Everything works fine, but MediaPlayer still shows its error log. I spent two days trying to solve that issue and I didn't find any solution neither to solve this error, nor to delete this error message from the logs.
The error in logcat:

```
E/MediaPlayer: setDataSource: IOException! uri=https://my-url
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://my-url
```

My code (and the whole app) works fine. The app successfully plays all the videos from the links and this error doesn't actually make any sense.
I found similar issue [here](http://community.ooyala.com/t5/Developers-Forum/Why-video-is-loading-2-times-with-FileNotFoundException-before-a/td-p/7899), as they say:

The message in the logs is a debug message built into the Android MediaPlayer. It is not an actual error.. They are using an exception for control flow. See the Android MediaPlayer.java's sources for setDataSource() for internal gory details.

Well, I don't care about this issue in my debug code, but I don't want to see any logs in my production app. I use proguard to delete all the logs from my app. 
My `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
public static *** v(...);
public static *** i(...);
public static *** w(...);
public static *** d(...);
public static *** e(...);
}

# for Okhttp:
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
# Okio (okhttp)
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# Glide specific rules #
# https://github.com/bumptech/glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
**[] $VALUES;
public *;
}

## Google Analytics 3.0 specific rules ##
-keep class com.google.analytics.** { *; }

# for search view #
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

# for jsoup #
-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes

# for share action provider #
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider { *; }
```

In my `build.gradle` file:

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

But nothing changes. So the question is:

How can I remove these log messages, in general, and remove the links in the logs, in particular, produced by MediaPlayer? If there is no chance to do it with proguard, what options I have? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: you can't

**Long answer**: ProGuard only processes code that is part of your application. The MediaPlayer is part of the runtime library installed on the device. When your application invokes the MediaPlayer, it uses the version that is installed on your device and ProGuard has no way to process this part and remove the respective logging calls.

Comment: Thanks for the long part of your answer, it's really helpful. But maybe you know, how can I delete the MediaPlayer logs with some other option?